# Посчитать md5 частей файла

Tags: linux, файлы, linux-mint, md5

Хочу разбить файл на части по гигабайту и для каждого из них посчитать md5.
Как это можно сделать без записи фрагментов файла на диск?

Ещё нужна возможность один из этих фрагментов разбить на фрагменты поменьше и посчитать для каждого из них.

Comment: читайте нужными порциями (`$ man dd`) в цикле и вычисляйте всё что надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хочу разбить файл на части по гигабайту и для каждого из них посчитать md5.
>   Как это можно сделать без записи фрагментов файла на диск?

например:

```
$ f=имя_файла
$ s=$((2**30)) # размер «порции»
$ n=$(($(stat -c %s $f)/$s)) # количество «порций» (размер файла/размер порции)
$ for ((p=0;p<=n;p++)); do dd if=$f bs=$s skip=$p count=1 2>/dev/null | команда; done
```

`команда` — то, что вам требуется для обработки извлечённой порции. например, `md5sum`

---

> Ещё нужна возможность один из этих фрагментов разбить на фрагменты поменьше и посчитать для каждого из них.

например:

```
$ f=имя_файла
$ s=$((2**10)) # размер «порции»
$ n=10 # количество «порций»
$ b=100 # сколько «порций» пропустить от начала файла
$ for ((p=b;p<=n+b-1;p++)); do dd if=$f bs=$s skip=$p count=1 2>/dev/null | команда; done
```